# WPF + Animation + Datatemplate

Tags: wpf, animation, datatemplate

[image: Green & Red Arrows]

Hi Experts,

I want to achieve a behavior that if "new value" is greater than "previous value" for a particular cell then I want to show a green color arrow as per the attached image above for "x" seconds and then it should fade away. And a red color arrow if "new value" is lower than "previous value".

Please guide how I can achieve it and it would be great if you can share some example.  How can I mix data templates, animation & shapes to achieve this behavior?

Thanks
SC

Comment: Please **edit all your question titles** that have not already been fixed by someone else, the question title is **not** supposed to consist of a string of tags, it should describe the problem/question as concisely as possible.

Comment: OK I will be careful from next time and describe it appropriately. Regards, //SC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go for the following:

1. in the viewmodel for the value, expose property `bool? isIncreasing`.
2. in the datatemplate for the value, set up a data trigger, which would show the appropriate arrow if `isIncreasing` is not null.

I don't see how animations are connected with the problem, however.

Comment: Thanks Vlad, I have similar logic to figure out if its going up or down but I just want to know how can I build ARROW using WPF animations/shapes. Or do I need to use an image? I am very poor at defining datatemplates... Regards, //SC

Comment: It's up to you, really. You can just use an image for the arrow, it's simpler. If you want your graphics to be scalable, you can use a Path instead. Something like this: `<Path Fill="Green" StrokeThickness="0" Data="M 5,10 L 0,8 2,8 2,10 8,10 8,8 10,8 z"/>`

Comment: And you still don't need animation for it.